# Determining Time Complexities for O(n), O(n^2), O(n^3) and O(2^n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Could someone check my work for this problem? I'm unsure if my reasoning is correct.

We have four algorithms with time complexities **O(n)**, **O(n^2)**, **O(n^3)**, and **O(2^n)**. Each algorithm solves a problem of size **10** in **2** seconds.

For a size **20**...

a) O(n) takes 4 seconds.

b) O(n^2) takes 16 seconds.

c) O(n^3) takes 64 seconds.

d) O(2^n) takes 1048576 seconds.

so, are my calculations correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite! The ratio of time taken is a function of the ratio of input size (according to the time complexity functions). Since this ratio is 2:1 for all algorithms, the O(n) function will take 2 times as long, the O(n^2) function will take 4 times as long, the O(n^3) function will take 8 times as long, and the O(2^n) function will take 2^10=1024 times as long. Since the time taken for the first problem size was 2, the above numbers are each multiplied by 2:

a) 4 seconds
b) 8 seconds
c) 16 seconds
d) 2048 seconds

(For a concrete example to see that this works, suppose the exact runtimes of each algorithm, respectively, are a) (n/10) * 2, b) (n/10)^2 * 2, c) (n/10)^3 * 2, and d) 2^(n-10) * 2 and notice that these would satisfy the base case conditions of the problem while producing the above answers).